# what does "partially opaque" mean for windows code?

Tags: windows, device-driver

I see in [the documentation for a windows OS "DRIVER_OBJECT"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544174%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that `A driver object is partially opaque`. But what does "partially opaque" mean?

I am guessing that means that only part of a DRIVER_OBJECT are avaialable, but then what, programatically speaking, does that mean? That is, if some code has a pointer to the DRIVER_OBJECT, then it can read (and possibly write) the whole object as one unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete quote is,

> A driver object is partially opaque. Driver writers must know about
>   certain members of a driver object to initialize a driver and to
>   unload it if the driver is unloadable. The following members of the
>   driver object are accessible to drivers.

The pertinent part is: Driver writers must know about **certain** members.

In order to write/use a driver you need certain parts of the code to be accessible. An **interface** of sorts. ( Without the language formalization that is). These members are explained in the document right after the above quote.

> Undocumented members within a driver object should be considered
>   inaccessible. Drivers with dependencies on object member locations or
>   on access to undocumented members might not remain portable and
>   interoperable with other drivers over time.

What this means is that while the required 'interface' is visible, anything else in the driver **should** be considered 'private'. Sure you can reach it in C, but this is unsupported and it may break, be un-portable, etc, etc.

This is the definition of partially opaque, opaque means '[not transparent](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/opaque)'. **Partially opaque** means it is **partially not transparent**, or conversely, it is **partially visible**. The use of *partially opaque* rather then *partially visible*, puts the emphasis on the hidden nature of the driver object, rather then the visible parts.